# Python: Recursive function for browsing all tree nodes

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I'm trying to make an recursive function which finds all nodes in a tree. My function, let's name it child(), can find all children of the current node and returns a list´of them.

```
global nodes
nodes = []

def func():
    if len(child(c))==0:
        return []
    else:
        for ch in child(c):
            nodes.append(ch)
            return func(ch)
```

It seems it does not work for some reason.

Do you have an idea whats wrong or the problem should be somewhere else in my code?

EDIT: The problem is probably

`if len(child(c))==0:
      return []`
it should check another child instead of return []. But don't know what to put there.

Comment: it does not work in what way?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, it does not, but the problem could be somewhere else in my code in case this is correct.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Found a problem maybe. If len(child(c))==0: return But it should check next neighbour...

Comment: if the len of child c is 0 how can there be a neighbour?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Let's have a look on this image http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#mediaviewer/File:Binary_tree.svg For example node 11 has no children but it has a neighbour which would not be checked in this case but it should be.

Comment: Is your graph a directed graph or undirected graph?

Comment: add your code and input

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In fact, it is a web bage browser. The web page consists of buttons which points to another pages etc. etc. Sometimes there is a button, which points to already checked page so it is not a directed tree. here is the code: http://pastebin.com/jBJZhk2Q

Answer (score 1):

it's because of the return statement inside the for, the function passed only on the first child in the list.

this should work

```
global nodes
nodes = []

def func(c):
    for ch in child(c):
        nodes.append(ch)
        func(ch)
```